# Carbon из строки в дату

Tags: laravel, carbon

есть дата 2018-12-01 (строка), как с помощью Carbon перевести в дату такого же формата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dt = Carbon::parse('2012-10-5 23:26:11.123789');

var_dump($dt->year);                                         // int(2012)
var_dump($dt->month);                                        // int(10)
var_dump($dt->day);                                          // int(5)
var_dump($dt->hour);                                         // int(23)
var_dump($dt->minute);                                       // int(26)
var_dump($dt->second);                                       // int(11)
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ в документации много примеров. Если указать только дату то `hour, minute, second`, будут равны 0

вот еще пример

```
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '1975-05-21 22')->toDateTimeString(); // 1975-05-21 22:00:00
```